# What does "gblinear" do in XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

For example, if I run a single round (`nrounds=1`), how does XGBoost go about making predictions?  I thought it would simply return a linear regression model, but I quickly shot that theory down by working out an example.

Please note that I've already seen [this](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/332) and [this](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md#general-parameters) and most of Google's top search results.

Answer (score -2):

`gblinear` uses linear functions, in contrast to `dart` which use tree based functions.

One primary difference between linear functions and tree-based functions is the decision boundary. Tree-based models decision boundaries are only piece-wise, perpendicular rules to each feature. Linear functions are monotonic lines through the feature space.

Tree-based functions tend to be more flexible. If the data is  distributed closer to a line, then a linear function will be more parsimonious.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which linear functions does it use?